# Google Apps Script Insert variable in complex string

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this string in a Google Apps Script

const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'Authorization': 'Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRv','Content-Type': 'application/json'}});
I can't find a working way to have the string "QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRv" read from a variable.

Something like
var key = "QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRv";
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'Authorization': 'Basic + key +','Content-Type': 'application/json'}});

Does not work!!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), like this:

```
  const key = 'QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRv';
  const auth = `Basic ${key}`;
  const headers = { 'Authorization': auth, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { 'method': 'POST', 'headers': headers });
```